# Adding new column in sencha grid before the last column

Tags: extjs, gxt

Suppose i have a sencha grid which has columns 
Name, Email, Address, Phone, City, State, Country

Now out this initially i am only displaying Name, Email, Address and Phone.

I have given the provision to display more columns, the pending ones, City, State and Country.

But the problem in that when ever i add a new column in the grid then it gets appended to the last...in my case suppose i add City then it gets appended after Phone...

But i want Phone to always remain the last column and if any other column is added then it should be prefixed before Phone column.

I am using sencha grid.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Are u using sencha ext js or gxt?

Answer (score 6):

Use headerCt for this. You can insert a new column to any position.

```
handler: function(btn) {
    var grid = btn.up('gridpanel');

    var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
        text: 'Country',
        dataIndex: 'country'
    });

    grid.headerCt.insert(
      grid.columns.length - 1, // that's index column
      column);

    grid.getView().refresh();
}
```

---

[**Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fpc)